# Horizontal scaling of search query

Tags: sql, postgresql, hadoop, apache-storm

We are building cv scoring service, and we are using Postgres for making complex queries to find cv's that match vacancy best.
The problem is, that we use really complex set of heuristics to score cv to vacancy, and the average number of cvs to be scored per query is growing.
I want to put this kind of load outside of database, and looking for existing solutions for horizontal scaling such load.
Query should be executed in fraction of a second, there can be hundreds of concurrent queries. Each query scores on average 10k cvs. Each cv is like about 50 records in maybe 10 tables in its current relational form.

I want a clustered system to run each query in multiple parallel processes (on many servers) and return aggregated result. It should be fast and fault tolerant.
I was looking to Hadoop, but it looks like it is designed for batch processing, and not for realtime low latency load. There is Apache Storm, but it is designed for continous stream processing. So I am not shure :)

What kind of tool could will suit my needs?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are not redoing work, if a cv has been scored tag it as scored and don't reprocess unless it's necessary.
2. Unless you are partitioning the data in postgres you might want to do that. Usually not all rows need to be accessed regularly.
3. Sounds like you want to primarily scale reads, in that case a postgres read-only cluster could be an option.
4. Take a look at Elasticsearch, it is designed to do weighted scoring, faceting, etc. It should also scale, haven't tried that myself though.

I would definitely start with 1 though, don't do work unless you have to.

Comment: Thanks Björn! 1) We are not redoing work, because cvs are scored to match vacancies, which nearly allways has different requirements. We need to score each cv each time. 2) Partitioning wont help, because most of the time ALL cvs are scored. Sharding of processing is what I want. 3) We have two node cluster, but single sql query is not distributed between nodes in vanilla postgres. 4) I'll take a look at elasticsearch, thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is not what we need. Elasticsearch is built on top of Lucene and it is fulltext search engine. We dont do fulltext search, and even dont do search. We apply scoring(cv,vacancy) to all cvs in database and return best matches.

Comment: Elasticsearch does much more than fulltext search.